# Problem setting up flutter using command-line tools

Tags: android, flutter

I'd like to use vscode as my main editor for flutter development. I successfully setup the commandline tools (**v6200805**) and created a virtual device using avdmanager. I was also able to launch the device using the `flutter emulators -launch` command.  However on using `flutter doctor` command, flutter does not recognize the sdk path. The latest version of the commandline tools follows a different file structure as compared to the previous version.

Also, I configured flutter to know the dir of Android sdk path using 
`flutter config — -android-sdk E:\IDEs\Android\cmdline-tools\` but to no luck.

How do i work around this problem?

[Error shown by flutter doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpTRY.png)

Comment: Think that I would try installing android studio and see if that fixes your problem, the messages from doctor suggest that it will.

Comment: Have you setup environment variables for android SDK ?

Comment: Ha, it worked! I somehow missed the ANDROID_SDK_ROOT variable.Thanks!